# Move field through different groups in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a question concerning Crystal Reports.

Imagine I have crystal report form with two groups: Group Header & Group Footer. Assuming the different fields found on the two groups is connected to the same database. Can I moves the fields through the different groups so as it does not affect the data or the connection to the database.

Because I have tried to redesign a report on crystal report, unfortunately when I move the field to a different group it did not the values from the database. I have also try to insert a new field & link it to the database. it does not work. Can someone help me please?

P.S: I am a beginner in Crystal Report.

Comment: could you please post your report in design view?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Because Group header and Footer make one single group. If you have 2 groups you must have 2 headers and 2 footers. Also what do you mean by "MOVE" the fields??

Comment: Ok... May I have not well explain. What I see on the page is a group header #1 and a group footer #1. footer #1 contains some fields which are linked to a database. The same for header #1. Unfortunately, when I want to move a field from footer #1 to the section header #1, the field did not display the required values. It seems that it lost connection to the database. I have try to find the field from Field Explorer. It shows me the required field from the database. But on the report there are no values.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement has nothing to do with the database connection... database connection well exists in your report....

Now coming to your requirement though you have one group and that group has group header and footer... data displayed will be different because group header will show you the first record with which you are grouping and in group footer you will have last record with which you are grouping.

Hope my explanation is clear.

If this is not you are looking for let me know... or explain more about your requirement.